# Integrating factor for nonexact differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> I have attempted the question:  $$\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{5y^4−2xy}{x^2}$$

I cannot find the integrating factor that only involved $x$ or $y$ and have tried other methods and still cant find the factor.

Is there another method that I haven't tried?

Comment: Uh okay, is it y’ = (5y^4-2xy)/x^2 or y’ = 5y^4 - 2xy/x^2? Parentheses do matter :/

Comment: Tried to interpret to the best of my ability, please check if this is what you meant

Comment: yeah sorry, it is  dy / dx = (5y^4−2xy) /  x^2

Comment: Would I be correct to say I need to use a Bernoulli Substitution?

Comment: That is correct Luke. Can you complete the problem after analyzing either of the two answers?

Answer (score 0):

> **Bernoulli Equation :** Differential equations in the form,$$y'+p(x)y=q(x)y^n$$where$~p(x)~$ and $~q(x)~$  are continuous functions on the interval we’re working on and $~n~$ is a real number. Differential equations in this form are called **Bernoulli Equations**.

Given differential equation is$$\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{5y^4−2xy}{x^2}$$
which can be written in the form $$y'+\dfrac 2xy=\dfrac 5{x^2}y^4$$
i.e., of the form$$y^{-4}y'+\dfrac 2xy^{-3}=\dfrac 5{x^2}\tag1$$
Let $~u=y^{-3}~$ then $~u'=-3y^{-4}y'~$, then the equation $(1)$ becomes 
$$-\dfrac 13 u'+\dfrac 2xu=\dfrac 5{x^2}$$
$$\implies u'-\dfrac 6xu=-\dfrac {15}{x^2}\tag2$$
which is a first order differential equation.

Integrating factor (I.F.) $~=e^{\int -(6/x) dx}=\dfrac{1}{x^6}~$

Multiplying both side of $(2)$ by I.F. we have
$$ \dfrac{1}{x^6}~u'-\dfrac{6}{x^7}u=-\dfrac {15}{x^8}$$
$$\implies d\left(\dfrac{1}{x^6}~u\right)=-\dfrac {15}{x^8}~dx$$
Integrating we have$$\dfrac{1}{x^6}~u=\dfrac{15}{7x^7}+c$$
$$\implies u=\dfrac{15}{7x}+c~x^6$$
$$\implies y^{-3}=\dfrac{15}{7x}+c~x^6$$where $~c~$ is integrating constant.

Hence the solution of the given differential equation $(1)$ is 
$$y=\sqrt[3]{\dfrac{7x}{15+7cx^7}~}$$where $~c~$ is integrating constant.

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{5y^4−2xy}{x^2}$$
$$y'x^2 +2xy= 5y^4$$
$$(x^2y)'=5y^4$$
Divide by $(x^2y)^4$. It's now separable:
$$\dfrac {(x^2y)'}{(x^2y)^4}=\dfrac 5 {x^8}$$
Integrate both sides.
$$\int \dfrac {d(x^2y)}{(x^2y)^4}=5 \int \dfrac {dx} {x^8}$$Can you take it from here ?